# Is it possible to create a pointer of type object instead of type class or structure?

Tags: c

Sorry if this question is poorly worded (please edit it if it will make it easier for readers to understand me.)

I'm new to oop and was learning some C code.  What does this last line of code mean?  Is there a way to paradigmatically(I just made up this word) write it differently?

```
typedef struct _Song {
//some members
} Song;

Song * pSong=0;
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
_Song * pSong=0;
```

Instead of:

```
Song * pSong=0;
```

...since Song is an object and _Song is a structure.

Comment: Song is not an object, but a typedef. And by the way, I removed the C++ tag, as this (even if compilable in C++) is no C++, but C code (but at least you didn't mention C/C++ ;)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Song` is nothing more than an alias for `struct _Song` (that's what the `typedef` at the beginning means). There is absolutely no difference between the two, wrt their type.

In C++, the syntactic difference is even more marginal, since `_Song` is also an alias for `struct _Song`.

Comment: Marcelo can you please elaborate on the syntax of what an underscore "_" means?  I was under the impression that for some code like this `struct product {
  int weight;
  float price;
} apple, banana, melon;`

apple, banana and melon are objects.  So shouldn't Song be an object of type _Song?

Comment: @LedZeppelin: `Song` is a type (alias of `struct _Song` like Marcelo said), because it was declared using a `typedef`.

Comment: An underscore doesn't mean anything. It's just what you used to name the struct. In fact, you shouldn't use names that begin with an underscore followed by an upper-case letter (they are reserve), but that doesn't affect my answer. And no, Song isn't an object of type _Song. It would be if you hadn't written `typedef` at the beginning.

Comment: @LedZeppelin. No, the struct in your post have a typedef, and by having that, the syntax for a struct is different. `struct product { int weight; float price; } apple` , here apple is indeed an object. but with `typedef struct product { int weight; float price; } apple` , apple is the alias name for struct product, not an object. The underscore is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

A `typedef` creates an alias for a type. You can write them inline with struct definitions to get short names for a struct. E.g.

```
typedef int** int_dbl_ptr;
```

Normally, if you defined `_Song` without a typedef, you'd have to write `struct _Song*`, but with the typedef it's just `Song*`.

You can also create structs inline with variable declarations, e.g.

```
struct foo {int bar; int baz; } a, b, c;
```

creates a struct of type `struct foo` and declares three `struct foo`s, `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Comment: Thanks Rafe, I misunderstood the syntax I posted in my question.  I thought I was creating an object after the structure declaration.